# Spelling Puzzle

Tags: no-computers, anagram

All right students, take your seats for the "Spelling Bee." Perhaps I should say "Arranging Bee." Listed are the names of seven countries of the world. For the test, I have scrambled the letters that make up each name of the countries. It's up to you to rearrange them correctly. Five out of seven will get you a passing grade.

1) NODPAL

2) DSNCAOLT

3) RILBAUGA

4) ELANP

5) GLEDANN

6) OANMARI

7) SATNKPIA

Hint:

> No need for one. Its super easy already!

WARNING:

> ***DON'T*** use ***UNSCRAMBLE*** or any other website or page from ***INTERNET*** or any where. Use ***ONLY*** your ***MIND*** for this ***RIDDLE***!

Comment: I don't think DNSCAOLT and GLEDANN should be on the list; they aren't independent, but parts of GIN-MOUNTED KID instead.

Comment: @ACoolGuy, can I please get the tick? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton ok i did :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton no problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:
 (1,2,3,4,7 credits to malioboro)

1.

> Poland

2.

> Scotland

3.

> Bulgaria

4.

> Nepal

5.

> England

6.

> Romania

7.

> Pakistan

Comment: lemme see someone else or u winner!

Comment: Oh no... I was used to using rot13(Havgrq Xvatqbz) for number 4 :( but I really have no Idea for 6th even after read M Oehm's comment, you are great! :)

Comment: i know, so i upvoted malioboro's ans, sorry @malioboro

Comment: what u mean @malioboro ? "I used to using rot13(Havgrq Xvatqbz) for number 4" ???

Comment: its a joke not a boy! i never said u a boy. Bad boy suits the joke not bad man because it looks like batman!

Comment: @ACoolGuy that country has many "different names" and I forgot one of them :)

Comment: np did u complete ur ans?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton thank god u understand :P

Comment: Im from SATNKPIA! Im SERIOUS!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84897/discussion-between-omega-krypton-and-a-cool-guy).

Comment: sure meet u there!

Answer (score 5):

PARTIAL ANSWER:

1.

> POLAND

2.

> SCOTLAND

3.

> BULGARIA

4.

> NEPAL

7.

> PAKISTAN

Comment: great effort! up-vote